# AnyLogic: Create multiple agents at the same time with different parameter value from database

Tags: anylogic

As the title says, I want to create multiple agents of the same type at a specific (same) time. For that I have a database table (imported from excel):
[image: Database table]

The arrival date gets imported from the column "time", the sum of agents per arrival gets imported from the column "total". So that at 00:00 the source creates 139 agents, at 00:15 the source creates 178 agents and so on. That works fine.

But now I also want to "split" the total of 139 agents (from 00:00) in six parts and give them a parameter. 24 agents should get the value 101 from my parameter "id", 9 agents should get the id 102, 31 agents should get the id 103...until 106.

Is that possible?

I tried multiple approaches. One is changing the database, so the parameter "id" is displayed in only one column. For that the database gets really long because each time has to occure six times (once for every id). Works, but not the best solution. The database should stay as it is.

Working with the database reference for Agents per arrival did not work for me.

Creating six sources can't be the best way to solve it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible, but needs some custom coding. Here is the zest:

- Read the data row by row at the model start
- for each row, create a Dynamic Event (not a normal Event!)
- pass the 6 arguments into the DE and trigger it at the date of the current row
- in the DE, create as many new agents as each argument's value using `add_SomeAgentPopulation(...)` and fill its parameter accordingly

Comment: Is it still the best (or only) way to do if my database is much larger, e.g. the data is for a whole day (4*24=96 rows) and the IDs are from 101-500 (400 colums)?

Comment: any database table with 400 columns is a bad design, sorry. Suggest you restructure the data first, this will cause a ton of issues either way :)